# Maximum sum of polynomial - choice of coefficient and variables

Tags: optimization, summation, proof-writing

There are two given arrays:
$[x_1,...,x_n] $ and  $[y_1, ..., y_n]$.
Our task is to make pair such that:  $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_j$$ is maximum.
I know that we should sort these arrays: 
$x_1 \le ...\le x_n$
$y_1\le ... \le y_n$
And now our pairs are:
$(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ..., (x_n, y_n)$.
However, I can't prove this fact. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

This is otherwise known as the Rearrangement Inequality.

Let's assume we have  $x_1\leq x_2\leq\dots x_n$.

Let $\sigma$ be some permutation.

Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_{\sigma(i)}$ is maximized.

Take some pair $x_i>x_j$. Since swapping $y_{\sigma(i)}$ and $y_{\sigma(j)}$ would not increase the summation, it follows that

$x_iy_{\sigma(i)}+x_jy_{\sigma(j)}\geq x_iy_{\sigma(j)}+x_jy_{\sigma(i)}$

$x_iy_{\sigma(i)}+x_jy_{\sigma(j)}-x_iy_{\sigma(j)}-x_jy_{\sigma(i)}\geq0$

$(x_i-x_j)(y_{\sigma(i)}-y_{\sigma(j)})\geq0$

Hence, it follows that $y_{\sigma(i)}\geq y_{\sigma(j)}$ for this product to hold.

Suppose there are equal values of $x_i$ in the sequence. There is no harm in sorting $y_{\sigma(i)}$ as it does not decrease the sum. Hence, it follows that the two sequences $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{y_{\sigma(i)}\}_{i=1}^n$, when sorted, produces the maximum sum.

Comment: I wrote about maximalization

Comment: I try to understand your proof:   You take pair $x_i > x_j$. It is clear that $y_{\sigma(i)} \ge y_{\sigma(j)}$.  So far I understand.  So true is that $x_i > x_j \Rightarrow  x_i > x_j$.  Now, it is sufficient to use 
transitiveness inequality.  Don't you   ?  BTW: It seems to me that you show: If sum is maximum then sequences may be sorted.

Comment: There might be repeated values inside the sequences. As such, the sequences may not be sorted. You can take $\{x\}_{i=0}^n$ to be a constant sequence, and any arrangement of $\{y\}_{i=0}^n$ will not change the sum.

Comment: Ok, I can see point: repeated valuse may cause that $y_{\sigma(i)} < y_{\sigma(j)}$.  So we have a problem. I don't undestand what is your idea on fixing this problem

Comment: We can attain the maximum when there are repeated values by sorting, but this way of attaining the maximum may not be unique.

Comment: Ok, but try to prove it. You say: we can. But why ? When elements are distinct your proof works, but what about duplicates ? Any argument ?